# Backbone.js sync override and save success/error callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm overriding `Backbone.sync` for a model so that I can send calls out to the appropriate URLs when some conditions are met.  How do I trigger a success or error callback like I would in `.save`?  Adding a `save` method to my model doesn't work, as it seems to balk at the new URL.

Code example below (coffeescript) :

```
  sync: (method, model, options) ->
    if options.changes.approval is true
      options.url = @approvalUrl()
    else if options.changes.decline is true
      options.url = @declineUrl()
    else
      return false
    Backbone.sync method, model, options
```

On success I'd like to fire the following trigger, which normally I could do with `success: (model, response)`, but can't get working here

```
jQuery(".user-line-item-summary").trigger "approveSucceeded", [@get("id"), msg, false]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to trigger on the backbone model itself. Take a look at:

[http://backbonejs.org/#trigger](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-trigger)